# Unable to resolve dependency tree error for my angular project

Tags: angular

When trying to install the npm packages using **npm i** command, I am getting the following exception:

[image]

My angular versions

> Angular CLI: 14.0.6
> Node: 16.15.0
> Package Manager: npm 9.1.2
>
> Angular: 13.3.3

Below is the package I want to install.

> npm i @ngx-translate/core

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to be able to figure out all the dependencies, but it can be time consuming.

Another thing you can do is to install the package without checking dependencies using the command below:

```
npm i @ngx-translate/core --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

There were conflicting problems with dependencies in general. I solved the problem with the following command.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```